# Let $\{X_n\}$ denote a symmetric random walk. Find $P(X_{10}=3)$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $\{X_n\}$ denote a symmetric random walk on the integers such that $X_n = \sum^n_{i=1} Y_i$ where  $Y_i=\pm1$,  each with probability $0.5$ and $X_0=0$.

Find $P(X_{10}=3)$. I know the formula for $P(X_n=0\mid X_0=0)$, but don't know how to apply it to other cases.

Comment: In this case you know that $X_0=0$, so $P(X_0=0)=1$ and $P(X_{10}=3)=P(X_{10}=3|X_0=0)P(X_0=0)=P(X_{10}=3|X_0=0)$.

Comment: Also, $X_n$ and $n$ have the same parity, so $P(X_{10}=3)=0$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Then, how about finding $P(X_{9}=3)$? Is it possible to find a formula for it?

Comment: Yes: $P(X_n=k)={n\choose \frac{n+k}{2}}2^{-n}$ if $k$ is an integer having the same parity as $n$.

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits to this question.